# Create A localhost & expose the server to internet?

Tags: xampp, localhost, portforwarding, static-ip-address

connect localhost over internet without web services (ngrok..etc), Simple Steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it can by easy steps:

> Create Static IP Pv4 (Allowing Coming Request Over Internet). [will be your private static ip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iRp1Nug0PU)

> Adding Ports which U Wanna To connect with, in your firewall. [add both (TCP/UDP)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMGPyZtdP00)

> Need Web Server (Xamp,Etc...). [good tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-f8N4FEQWyY)

> In Router Gateway login, then Add Ports u want (example 80 [TCP+UDP]) in port mapping, u maybe will need too enable DMZ (in Advanced Option) and add the host address which have your local ip / or ur machine which host the server.

> in the end try to navigate your public server Example : http://***.***.**.**:port/dashboard/

if you get error, don't hesitate to say, that will allow to improve the Post.!